# VGG-16 and ResNet-9 loss values not corresponding to accuracy on test set

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, loss-function, cross-entropy

I have two models whose performance I am comparing, a ResNet-9 model and a VGG-16 model. They are being used for image classification. Their accuracies on the same test set are:

ResNet-9 = 99.25% accuracy

VGG-16 = 97.90% accuracy
[image: Losses of ResNet-9]

[image: Losses of VGG-16]

However from their loss curves during training, shown in the images, I see that the VGG-16 has lower losses as compared to ResNet-9 which has higher losses.

I am using torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss() for both VGG-16 and ResNet-9. I would have expected the ResNet-9 to have lower losses (because it performs better on the test set) but this is not the case.

Is this observation normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the loss for a model can be greater even if the accuracy is greater. This is because the loss function penalizes if the confidence is lower.

For example:
if you have a label `[0, 0, 0, 1]`,
and model A predicts `[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.7]`
and model B predicts `[0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]`
Both models will have an accuracy of 100% but the CrossEntropyLoss for model A will be greater than that of model B because model A predicts with a lower confidence score.

So, a higher loss of ResNet-9 compared to VGG-16, even when ResNet-9 has a greater accuracy, means ResNet-9's predictions (on average) have less confidence on the predicted labels.